# How to load/fill a object before widget build in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a message option window to show the users available for chat, where I load a list which I fill in initstate(). I could see the data being filled in debugger, but not getting displayed at first time. When I do hot reload its working? What am I missing here?

```
class _ChatwindowState extends State<Chatwindow> { List<ChatUsers> chatwithPeople=[]; 
@override void initState(){  super.initState();  setState(() { this.chatwithPeople=peopletomessage(); });}
 @override void dispose() { super.dispose(); }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Messages'),),
  body:databindUsers(context,widget.currentUser,this.chatwithPeople)
  );
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `FutureBuilder` for it like

```
FutureBuilder(
      future: peopletomessage(),//it will return the future type result
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        
        if(snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
          return databindUsers(context,widget.currentUser,this.chatwithPeople);
        }
        return _progress(); //show loading
      })
```